# Extracting and replacing filename extensions in Perl

Tags: perl

Before I start off, I'd like to let you know that I'm no Perl expert. I'm just starting out because of some specific tasks assigned to me.

The requirement of this task is to extract the extension of the file (`.dat`) and replace it with `.trg`. The problem is we are zipping the `.dat` file to make `$filename.dat.gz` and when we extract the extension and replace it we get `$filename.dat.trg` while want we would ideally want is `$filename.trg`.

As for the code (mind you, this seems to be a very old 'legacy' code and I don't want to tinker with it too much as it was/is being maintained by another person), this is how it is put down

```
#prepare the trigger file
#get the extension  
my @contains_extension = split (/\./ , $filename);
my $ext = $contains_extension[-1];

#replace with  a ".trg" extension
my $remote_trgfile = $filename;
$remote_trgfile =~ s/$ext$/trg/;
my $trgfile = $out;
$trgfile =~ s/$ext$/trg/;
```

Remember `$filename` in the above code is suffixed with `.dat.gz` i.e., the filename is `$filename.dat.gz`

I would appreciate if someone could help me out with an easier way to extract both the extensions (`.dat` and `.gz`) and replacing it with `.trg`

Comment: I do believe that this code is Perl, not PHP.

Comment: my bad, changed it appropriately..

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you need that is different from `s/\.dat\.gz$/.trg/` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to change the 'extension' of a filename, including a optional `.gz`? Try:

```
$filename =~ s{\.[^.]*(?:\.gz)?$}{.trg}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$filename =~ s/\..*$/.trg/;
```

no need to do all of that fancy splitting stuff to try and capture the extension :)

breakdown:

. matches .
.* matches everything (except newline)
$ matches the end of the string

then you're just replacing that with .trg

so you're basically just taking everything after the first "." and replacing with .trg

hope that helps :)

Comment: and what if the filename contains a `.` (which is perfectly valid in a *nix environment)?

Comment: then s/\..*?$/.trg/ otherwise there's no way to tell